# What is wrong with this function? Javascript and FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my asp.net project (built in VS using C#) I have a page that is reached when user is logged in.
I try to make a funktion for logout where the user clicks on a link and is logged out and transfered to page index.aspx.

Javascript:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function clicklink()
     {
         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
         document.getElementById('logout').click();
     }
     </script>
```

Asp.net:

```
   <td class="auto-style42"><a href="index.aspx" id="logout" onclick="clicklink()">Logout</a>
```

The error message I get is that FormsAuthentication is not defined. How do I define it, or are there other solutions?

Thanks for your help

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` is not JavaScript

Comment: You're confusing client-side and server-side code. There is not much we can do for you at this juncture, I would suggest you get more familiar with your environment first, before asking.

Comment: FormsAuthentication is a server side function

Comment: FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); is available in C# not in java script. so you can't write this code here. what do you want do with this code plz explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a server side `click` event to the `logout` link/button.  This will add a method called `logout_click` in the c# code.  Place `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` in that function.

**EDIT**

Just seen the mark up

Remove the javascript and change the ASP.NET to

```
 <td class="auto-style42">
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="logout" OnClick="logout_Click" Text="Logout" />
```

In your code behind enter the following event

```
protected void logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

FormAuthentication.Signout() is a server side function.

That is why you get the error message:
FormsAuthentication is not defined.

In order to implement your requirement, you should use ajax to invoke a backend method to instead of FormAuthentication.Signout(). The FormAuthentication.Signout() code should be placed at the backend method.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments says, you are mixing up client side code and server side code. If we take a look at your asp.net code:

```
<td class="auto-style42"><a href="index.aspx" id="logout" onclick="clicklink()">Logout</a>
```

onclick="clicklink" means that you have a event handler for the click event of the link at **server side**, so you need an event handler that for instance calls FormsAuthentication.SignOut(), whih also is **server side** code, and not javascript.

If you really want the javascript code to be executed when the link is clicked, you have to use OnClientClick="clicklink". But you can't have a call to FormsAuthentication.SignOut() in the javascript code, as it is server side code. The way to do it with javascript, is to call the asp.net code through the script, but in your case I would go with the first solution, writing a event handler for the onclick event.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Dreamwalker.To you others, thank you. And yes, it confuses me with server side and client side. And yes, I will read more.
Here is my final solution.

C#:

```
    protected void Logout_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();  
        Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
    }
```

And:

```
    <td class="auto-style42"><a href="#" onServerClick="Logout_Click" runat="server">Logout</a>
```